# SQL Server - Removing duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my table look like. I want to delete the records which has a corresponding 'deleted' status. Please see the output example:

```
ID-------VisitDate---------Name-----Status
abc123 - 2014-08-01 10:30  -john   -null
abc123 - 2014-08-01 10:35 - john- deleted
abc123 - 2014-08-02 12:30 - john - null

yyz999 - 2014-08-02 08:30 - Tom - null
xyz999 - 2014-08-01 08:31 - Tom- deleted
xyz999 - 2014-08-02 12:30 - Tom - null
pqr879 - 2014-08-05 11:10  - Anny - null
```

Expected Output:

```
ID-------VisitDate---------Name-----Status
abc123 - 2014-08-02 12:30 - john - null
xyz999 - 2014-08-02 12:30 - Tom - null
pqr879 - 2014-08-05 11:10  - Anny - null
```

Comment: Do you want sql delete command

Answer (score 0):

Please try using CTE:

```
with c as
(
    select 
        *, 
        row_number() over(partition by id order by Status) as n
    from tbl
)
delete from c
where n > 1;
```

Comment: I think the question is two-fold: delete the duplicates and the rows where `Status = deleted`. Adding `OR Status = 'deleted'` to the `WHERE` clause should handle it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to keep all records since the last `deleted`.  If so:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             max(case when status = 'deleted' then VisitDate end) over
                 (partition by id) as DeletedVisitDate
      from table t
     )
delete from todelete
    where VisitDate <= DeletedVisitDate;
```

If you just want a query to fetch these records:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             max(case when status = 'deleted' then VisitDate end) over
                 (partition by id) as DeletedVisitDate
      from table t
     )
select *
from todelete
where VisitDate > DeletedVisitDate or DeletedVisitDate is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete records with status deleted, use the following:

```
DELETE FROM TableName WHERE status = 'deleted'
```

Also, your expected output looks like you only want the maximum Visit Date to appear, so you can use the following SELECT query after running the DELETE.

```
SELECT ID, MAX(VisitDate) AS VisitDate, Name, Status 
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY ID, Name, Status
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID VARCHAR(10),VisitDate DATE, Name VARCHAR(10),Status VARCHAR(10) )
INSERT INTO @T (ID,VisitDate,Name,Status)VALUES('abc123','2014-08-01','john',NULL)
INSERT INTO @T (ID,VisitDate,Name,Status)VALUES('abc123','2014-08-02','john','deleted')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,VisitDate,Name,Status)VALUES('abc123','2014-08-03','john',NULL)
INSERT INTO @T (ID,VisitDate,Name,Status)VALUES('yyz999','2014-06-04','Tom',NULL)
INSERT INTO @T (ID,VisitDate,Name,Status)VALUES('yyz999','2014-06-02','Tom','deleted')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,VisitDate,Name,Status)VALUES('pqr879','2014-07-01','Anny',NULL)
INSERT INTO @T (ID,VisitDate,Name,Status)VALUES('pqr879','2014-07-01','Anny',NULL)
INSERT INTO @T (ID,VisitDate,Name,Status)VALUES('pqr879','2014-07-02','Anny','DELETED')

;WITH CTE AS
(
select distinct x.ID,X.VisitDate,X.Name,X.Status,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY x.ID ORDER BY X.Status )As Total from 
(Select a.ID,a.VisitDate,a.Name,a.Status from @T a
GROUP BY a.ID,a.VisitDate,a.Name,a.Status) X 
GROUP BY x.ID,X.VisitDate,X.Name,X.Status
)

Select DISTINCT C.ID,MAX(VisitDate)Dt,C.Name,C.Status from CTE C
WHERE C.Status IS NULL
GROUP BY C.ID,C.Name,C.Status
ORDER BY Dt DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select id, visitdate,name, status
from table t 
whete t.status <> 'deleted'
```